# Converting from 1Mbyte to Hex

Tags: binary, size, microprocessors

I am having problem understanding the following text,

> `8088` supports `1` Mbyte of external memory. This memory space is
>   organized from a software point of view as individual bytes of data
>   stored at consecutive address over the address range `00000` to `FFFFF`.

Now I don't get how the author converted from 1 Mbyte to FFFFF. Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1 Megabyte is `2^20`.  That means that you need 20 bits to represent it.  The range `00000-FFFFF` holds all possible values of 20 bits.

Answer (score 3):

It is well explained in pages describing the [8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8086) (the 8088 has the same instruction set architecture, but with slightly different pins).

Basically a segment register gave a (16 bits) base address which was multiplied by 16, then an 16 bits offset was added.

And `0xfffff` is 2<sup>20</sup>-1, i.e. 1048575

Answer (score 0):

Please diatinguish between CAPACITY and ADDRESSING. Capacity count start from 1, but in memory Addressing start from 0 ( address 0 is counted1).

An analogy. if we have capacity 10, and we address from 0, it would be from 0  to 9.

So the trick for addressing is 
Last Address = Capacity - 1.

For Capacity 1MB (dec) in Hex = 10.0000h
And for addressing, last address is 10.0000 - 1 = F FFFF
So addressiing for 1MB capacity is from 0 to F FFFF.
(Remember address 0, is counted 1).